# Firebase Rules - Cannot store user data on first login

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-security, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am pretty new to Firebase and I am having trouble with my security rules. I have an android client that registers or logs in a new user. On that user's first login, I save their data to the firebase like so:

```
public void onAuthenticated(AuthData authData) {
                //Save user data to firebase
                Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                map.put("provider", authData.getProvider());
                ref.child("users").child(authData.getUid()).updateChildren(map);
}
```

(This is called in onAuthenticated() when authenticating a user)

However, it seems that my security rules are not allowing the user to write to the database unless their data is already stored. My rules are as follows:

```
{
"rules": {
   "users":{
      "$userid": {
        ".read": "auth.id == $userid && auth !== null",
        ".write": "auth.id == $userid && auth !== null"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Also, if it matters, here's an example of what the data looks like when it actually is stored:
[image: an example]

How should I modify my rules to allow the client to write the user data once it authenticates with the server?

EDIT: After some testing, it appears that these rules do not allow the user to write anything to their user node, even if it already exists.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a typo in your rules You have:

```
    ".write": "auth.id == $userid && auth !== null"
```

That should be `auth.uid`, not `auth.id`.

I would also do the null check first.

So:

```
    ".write": "auth !== null && auth.uid == $userid"
```

Comment: For background, the check for null isn't necessary in this case. Security rules will fail if the auth object is accessed and it is not an object. But it doesn't hurt to have it, and can be helpful when writing rules like this (where the auth.uid would prevent the second part of the rule from executing): `auth.uid === 'frank' || (auth === null && root.child('foo').val() === 'bar')`

Comment: Oooh... I like that `auth.uid === 'frank'` rule. Can we get that injected into every Firebase out there please?